# Convert list in data frame collapsing one column and keeping others unaletered in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list formed by 12 elements, each being a data frame. Each df contain three columns, two common columns across all the elements and one different.

The two common columns are:

- `coche_OEM`
- `dia_hora_OEM`

The other column, which is different in every element, can be collapsed in an unique column when converting the list into a data frame. For instance, column `U0073` in one of the elements containS one value with the same name, whereas column `B1182` contains another element with the same name as the variable name.

The issue is that I would like to convert this list into a data frame with three columns (variables):

- `coche_OEM`
- `dia_hora_OEM`
- `DTC`: this column with all the values present in each column with their codes.

The list is this one:

```
listdf <- list(structure(list(B1182 = structure(1L, .Label = c("B1182", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(3L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1577774413, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(B1182 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B1182", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), 1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("B1182", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("B1182", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(B124D = structure(1L, .Label = c("B124D", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(3L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1577774413, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(B124D = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B124D", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), 1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("B124D", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("B124D", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(P2000 = structure(1L, .Label = c("c(\"P2000\", \"P2000\", \"P2000\")", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(5L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1577793330, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(P2000 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("c(\"P2000\", \"P2000\", \"P2000\")", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 1L, integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("P2000", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("P2000", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(U3003 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("NULL", 
"U3003"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(5L, 1L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(c(1577793330, 
1582648789), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    U3003 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("NULL", "U3003"), class = "factor"), 
    coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", "356232050836666", 
    "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
    "356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
        integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
        2L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 1L, integer(0))), .Names = c("U3003", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("U3003", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(B1D01 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("B1D01", "c(\"B1D01\", \"B1D01\")", "NULL"), class = "factor"), 
    coche_OEM = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
    "356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", 
    "356232050899078", "356232050905933"), class = "factor"), 
    dia_hora_OEM = structure(c(1581690876, 1582648789, 1582651926
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    B1D01 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B1D01", "c(\"B1D01\", \"B1D01\")", 
    "NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", "356232050836666", "356232050880755", 
    "356232050882736", "356232050899078", "356232050905933"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(2L, 1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
        integer(0), 3L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
        integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
        integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("B1D01", "coche_OEM", 
".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("B1D01", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(U0155 = structure(2L, .Label = c("NULL", 
"U0155"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(1L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1582648789, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(U0155 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NULL", 
"U0155"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("U0155", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("U0155", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(C1B00 = structure(1L, .Label = c("C1B00", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(1L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1582648789, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(C1B00 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("C1B00", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1L, integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("C1B00", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("C1B00", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(P037D = structure(2L, .Label = c("NULL", 
"P037D"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(1L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1582648789, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(P037D = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NULL", 
"P037D"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("P037D", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("P037D", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(P0616 = structure(2L, .Label = c("NULL", 
"P0616"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(1L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1582648789, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(P0616 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NULL", 
"P0616"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("P0616", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("P0616", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(P0562 = structure(2L, .Label = c("NULL", 
"P0562"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(1L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1582648789, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(P0562 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NULL", 
"P0562"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("P0562", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("P0562", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(U0073 = structure(2L, .Label = c("NULL", 
"U0073"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(1L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1582648789, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(U0073 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NULL", 
"U0073"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 
    1L, integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("U0073", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("U0073", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")), structure(list(P0138 = structure(1L, .Label = c("c(\"P0138\", \"P0138\", \"P0138\")", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(5L, .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), dia_hora_OEM = structure(1583391111, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(P0138 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("c(\"P0138\", \"P0138\", \"P0138\")", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), coche_OEM = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("356232050832996", 
"356232050836666", "356232050880755", "356232050882736", "356232050899078", 
"356232050905933"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), 1L, integer(0), integer(0), 
    integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0), integer(0))), .Names = c("P0138", 
"coche_OEM", ".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), .Names = c("P0138", "coche_OEM", 
"dia_hora_OEM")))
```

So, how could I convert this list into a data frame with my requirements?

Comment: The `dput` of list seems incomplete. Doesn't load the data.

Comment: That's weird, I copy/pasted from the question above just to be certain it works properly, and it worked for me. Could you please retry?

Comment: No, it doesn't on my system. Tried multiple times, restarting R as well. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Are you aware that some of the df in the list have rows that contains `c(c(\"P2000\", \"P2000\", \"P2000\")`, meaning a string representation of a vector?

Comment: I know these rows exist, I will try to filter it later. Did you succeed loading the data @GGamba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rename all the columns that are not 'coche_OEM' or 'dia_hora_OEM' to a predefined string ('id' here):

```
map_df(listdf, ~rename_at(.x, vars(-c('coche_OEM', 'dia_hora_OEM')), ~'id'))
```

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   id, coche_OEM [78]
   id                                   coche_OEM       dia_hora_OEM       
   <chr>                                <fct>           <dttm>             
 1 "B1182"                              356232050880755 2019-12-31 06:40:13
 2 "B124D"                              356232050880755 2019-12-31 06:40:13
 3 "c(\"P2000\", \"P2000\", \"P2000\")" 356232050899078 2019-12-31 11:55:30
 4 "U3003"                              356232050899078 2019-12-31 11:55:30
 5 "U3003"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
 6 "B1D01"                              356232050836666 2020-02-14 14:34:36
 7 "B1D01"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
 8 "c(\"B1D01\", \"B1D01\")"            356232050832996 2020-02-25 17:32:06
 9 "U0155"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
10 "C1B00"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
11 "P037D"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
12 "P0616"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
13 "P0562"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
14 "U0073"                              356232050832996 2020-02-25 16:39:49
15 "c(\"P0138\", \"P0138\", \"P0138\")" 356232050899078 2020-03-05 06:51:51
```